# Declared variables are reset in select statement

Tags: mysql, h2

I am trying to recreate a query from mysql to h2 database but getting inconsistent results.

The query

```
SELECT
    enrolmentid,
    @prev,
    questionid,
    @thisrow:= (
        CASE WHEN @prev = enrolmentid THEN
            @thisrow
        ELSE
            0
        END) + 1 AS row_num,
    @prev:= enrolmentid
FROM
    response,
    (SELECT @thisrow:= 0, @prev:= NULL) r
WHERE
    enrolmentid = 18620674
ORDER BY
    enrolmentid,
    questionid
```

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `enrolment` (
  `enrolmentid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `batch_reference` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `destination` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enrolment_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `enrolment_reference` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `response_report_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`enrolmentid`),
  KEY `FK9ueb1l045x7ignakryx64deir` (`response_report_id`)
);
```

Using MySQL the row_num is correctly incremented:

```
enrolmentid,@prev,questionid,row_num,@prev:= enrolmentid
18620674,NULL,33909,1,18620674
18620674,18620674,33910,2,18620674
18620674,18620674,33911,3,18620674
```

But H2 appears to reset the variables for each row

```
ENROLMENTID,@PREV,QUESTIONID,ROW_NUM,"SET(@PREV, ENROLMENTID)"
18620674,NULL,33909,1,18620674
18620674,NULL,33910,1,18620674
18620674,NULL,33911,1,18620674
```

Does anyone know of a consistent way to achieve this between MySQL and H2? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of session variables inside a select list lead to undefined results in H2, because rows can be evaluated in any order.

If you use modern versions of MySQL and H2 you can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY enrolmentid ORDER BY questionid)` instead of such complex and unreliable expression.

```sql
SELECT
    enrolmentid,
    questionid,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY enrolmentid ORDER BY questionid)
FROM
    response
WHERE
    enrolmentid = 18620674
ORDER BY
    enrolmentid,
    questionid
```

If your `WHERE` condition always has only one `enrolmentid`, the `PARTITION BY` clause isn't needed, `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY questionid)` will be enough.

Comment: Absolutely spot on. Thank you so much